# How to detect PutItem operation in DynamoDB using lambda trigger?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb, aws-lambda, amazon-sns

I have a function in `AWS Lambda` which is triggered by an operation in `AWS DynamoDB`. The function contains this code which suppose to send a new push message using `AWS SNS`:

```
console.log('Loading function');

var AWS = require('aws-sdk');  
AWS.config.region = 'us-west-2';

exports.handler = function(event, context) {  
    console.log("\n\nLoading handler\n\n");
    var sns = new AWS.SNS();

    sns.publish({
        Message: 'Test publish to SNS from Lambda',
        TopicArn: 'TOPIC_ARN'
    }, function(err, data) {
        if (err) {
            console.log(err.stack);
            return;
        }
        console.log('push sent');
        console.log(data);
        context.done(null, 'Function Finished!');  
    });
};
```

How can I trigger this `Lambda` code only when a `PutItem` operation happens in the `DynamoDB` table?

Besides, is there a way where I could get the attributes of the new added item to the table and check if one of them is equal to a string?

[This](https://forums.aws.amazon.com/thread.jspa?threadID=237945&tstart=0) is my question in AWS Developer Forums.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
// Check if it is PutItem event
if (record.eventName == "INSERT") {
    ...
    // Get item's id
    var id = record.dynamodb.Keys.Id.N;
    ...
}
```

Comment: Please edit with more information. Code-only and "try this" answers are discouraged, because they contain no searchable content, and don't explain why someone should "try this".